# Receive object sent through POST from Javascript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, post

In Javascript (with JQuery) I send an object via post as follows:

```
var myobj = {};
myobj['test'] = 1;
myobj['child'] = {};
myobj['child']['test2'] = 2;
var myvar = 123;
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: myobj,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Now in PHP I receive the object through the $_POST variable.  I would like to access this object as a multidimensional array.  How would I reference this object/variable and its contents?

What if I wanted to send (POST) another variable (myvar) along with myobject?  How do I send both, and how would I access them in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can jsonify the object before sending to PHP handler.

Your javascript can be like this:

```js
var myobj = {};
myobj['test'] = 1;
myobj['child'] = {};
myobj['child']['test2'] = 2;
var myvar = 123;
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: {myobj: JSON.stringify(myobj), myvar: myvar},
  success: success,
  dataType: "json"
});
```

And you can access the `data`  as a multidimensional array in PHP like this:

```php
$data = json_decode($_POST, true);
// $data['myobj'] contains the object
// $data['myvar'] contains the var
```

Comment: Is the $data[myobj] now an associative array in PHP?